# how to get records form a table based on particular values in a column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
id fulltank vehicle number
1   Yes        123
2   Yes        456
3   No         123
4   No         123
```

So I wanted to get rows with id 3 and 4. I mean I should get all records with "No" `fulltank`.

If :

```
id fulltank vehicle number
1   Yes       123
2   Yes       456
3   No        123
4   No        123
5   Yes       123
6   No        123
7   No        123
8   No        123
9   Yes       456
```

Then I should get rows with id 6,7,8 (of a particular vehicle). That means records after "Yes" to last inserted row with "No".

User every time selects whether he is filling the tank completely or not if he is filling completely `fulltank` will be recorded as "Yes" or if he is filling it with 45 or 75 or something it will be recorded as "No". When the user is filling it completely (ie., `fulltank` is "Yes") need to get all the records of previously created/inserted rows with "No" values (ie., only records after last - `fulltank` "Yes" of a particular vehicle).

Comment: FWIW, I think you accepted the wrong answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide this into 3 steps:

- First is to get the max ID of the row which has fulltank = 'No'
- Second is to get the max ID of the row which has fulltank = 'Yes' but it's ID is less than the first step's ID.
- Third is to get all rows which have ID between second step's ID + 1 and first step's ID.

**Query:**

```
select *
from test_table
where id between 
            (select max(id) from test_table where fulltank = 'Yes' and id < (select 
                                max(id) from test_table where fulltank = 'No')) + 1                                                                                      
          and                                                                                        
             (select max(id) from test_table where fulltank = 'No')
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJzMz3eGH3KLLQVkyjmhP/0

Comment: The plus one bit assumes something which simply isn't necessarily true (and it's an unnecessary assumption)

Comment: @Strawberry Op said _(ie., only records after last - fulltank "Yes" of a particular vehicle)._ So, technically a `Yes` seems to be present always. If it isn't, then don't return any records which my query does.

Comment: But that's not the false assumption

Comment: @Strawberry Neither true until OP clarifies it.

Comment: @swetha Will  a row with `Yes` be present always? If not present. you want to get `No` records even then? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes i did the same thing but in reverse way i first found id of "Yes" and found last "No" and get all rows between them.

Comment: @swetha Glad to help but can you please clarify my previous question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` query to find all rows with `fulltank = 'No'` for a given vehicle where there is no row with `fulltank = 'Yes'` with a higher `id` value:

```
SELECT *
FROM fuel f1
WHERE fulltank = 'No'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM fuel f2
                  WHERE f2.vehicle_number = f1.vehicle_number
                    AND f2.id > f1.id
                    AND f2.fulltank = 'Yes'
                  )
```

Output (for your second table sample)

```
id  fulltank    vehicle_number
6   No          123
7   No          123
8   No          123
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/052a0c/1)